# Exploring Options for a Document Editor Implemented Exclusively with Pure JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, text-editor

I am currently engaged in the development of a website wherein users are required to compose reports that necessitate conversion to the .docx format for subsequent emailing and printing. In pursuit of an adept document editor tailored to these specifications, I have explored commonly utilized options such as CKEditor and TinyMCE, yet these solutions do not align with the desired functionality. I am seeking recommendations for an alternative document editor that fulfills the specified requirements. Your assistance in guiding me towards a suitable solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few editors that can run in the browser. You might even be able to find a way to create docx files using a LibreOffice application compiled to WASM.

Comment: you can rename a .html file .docx and it will open in word.

Comment: " yet these solutions do not align with the desired functionality" .... how do they not align?

Comment: I checked LibreOffice WASM but he doesn't have a offline mode yet

Comment: I checked out TinyMCE ,CKEditor , but they lack some advanced features we need like embedded charts, analytics tools, and advanced page design